# rotate text in tabular array

Tags: rotating, tabularray

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%------ tables
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{bgodd}{black!10}
\usepackage{tabularray}
     \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
%------



\begin{document}

bla bla bla

\clearpage
\newpage

\clearpage
\newpage

\begin{sidewaystable*}[ht]
    
    \centering
    \caption{Papers analyzed in the survey grouped by data sources employed, and techniques used to detect anomalies.}
    %\caption{Papers analyzed in the survey grouped by data sources employed, and techniques used to detect anomalies}
    % from makecell
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{\small Monitoring-Based}
    \footnotesize
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0.1mm} % let LaTeX calculate intercolumn whitespace
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\textheight-3\baselineskip,  % <--- added
        colspec = {l *{13}{X[c]}},
        vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{dotted},
        vline{2,5} = {1-Z}{solid, \lightrulewidth}, % \lightrulewidth is defined in booktabs
        colsep = 1pt,                               % <--- changed
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
        row{2} = {cmd=\rotcell},
        row{odd [3-Y]} = {bg=bgodd},                % <--- changed
        }
        \toprule
        \SetRow{bg=white}
        Paper(s) &
        \SetCell[c=3]{c, m} {Data\\ Sources} &&&
            \SetCell[c=10]{c, m} Technique &&&&&&&&& \\
        \midrule
        & Log-based
            & Distributed Tracing-based
            & Monitoring-Based
            & {Unsupervised\\ learning}
            & {Supervised\\ learning}
            & Reinforcement learning
            & Semi-supervised learning
            & Hybrid learning
            & {Statistical\\ Approach}
            & Causal Inference
            & {Trace\\ comparison}
            & Heart Beating
            & SLO checks \\
        \midrule
        \cite{liu2020unsupervised, pahl2018all, jin2020anomaly, bogatinovski2020self} &
        &  % Log-based
        \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
           % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{nedelkoski2019anomaly, gan2019leveraging, zhou2019latent} &
        &  % Log-based
        \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{wang2020workflow, chen2020framework, meng2021detecting} &
        &  % Log-based
        \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        \textbullet &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{li2021microservice} &
        &  % Log-based
        \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        \textbullet &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{chow2014mystery} &
        &  % Log-based
        \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        \textbullet &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{belhadi2021reinforcement} &
        &  % Log-based
        \textbullet &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        \textbullet &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{sharma2013cloudpd, zhang2016taskinsight, xu2018unsupervised, gulenko2018detecting, mariani2018localizing, wu2020microrca, wu2020performance, wang2018cloudranger, vallis2014novel, su2019robust, huang2013lof, bhaduri2011detecting,wang2012workload, lazarevic2003comparative} &
        &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
        \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{sauvanaud2018anomaly, liu2015opprentice, du2018anomaly, mariani2020predicting} &
        &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{magalhaes2010detection, peiris2014pad, abdelrahman2016detection, kang2012dapa, yang2007anomaly, wang2013energy, ahad2015toward, nguyen2013fchain, tan2012prepare, gu2009online, samir2019dla} &
        &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        \textbullet &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{wu2021causal, chen2014causeinfer, chen2016causeinfer, lin2018microscope} &
        &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        \textbullet &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
         % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{shan2019diagnosis} &
        &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        \textbullet  % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{zang2018fault} &
        &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        \textbullet &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        \textbullet  &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{yagoub2018equipment, brown2018recurrent, nandi2016anomaly, jia2017logsed, fu2009execution, du2017deeplog} &
        \textbullet &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        \textbullet &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{fronza2013failure, zhang2016automated, zhang2019robust, liang2007failure} &
        \textbullet &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        \textbullet &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{meng2019loganomaly} &
        \textbullet &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        \textbullet &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
       \cite{meng2019loganomaly, yang2021semi, li2021microservice} &
        \textbullet &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        \textbullet &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        &   % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{salfner2007using, beschastnikh2014inferring} &
        \textbullet &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        &   % Hybrid learning
        \textbullet &  % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
        \cite{he2020loghub} &
        \textbullet &  % Log-based
        &   % Distributed Tracing-based
        &   % Monitoring-Based
        &   % Unsupervised learning
        &   % Supervised learning
        &   % Reinforcement learning
        &   % Semi-supervised learning
        \textbullet &   % Hybrid learning
        &  % Statistical Approach
        &   % Causal Inference
        &   % Trace comparison
        &   % HeartBeating
        % SLO checks 
        \\
        \midrule
    \end{tblr}  
    {\label{tab:tbl_results}}
\end{sidewaystable*}

\clearpage
\newpage

bla bla

\end{document}
```

Printscreen:

[image]

I have to rotate from the second row, so it is readable, i.e., 270 degrees. I am not succeeding with the rotcell command in line 41. Do you know how to rotate the text of this line?

The goal is :

[image]

Solution:

I have added @Celdor's solution:

```
\renewcommand\cellrotangle{270}
```

And it worked.

Thank you.

Comment: I think you might be asking about an angle the `\rotcell` rotates the cells by. You have to redefine `\cellrotangle`, that is add this in preamble `\renewcommand\cellrotangle{270}` (see more info in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell)).

Comment: Thanks Celdor, it worked!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment (as OP said in question).

Comment: I don't think that the question should be closed, since it has a seemingly valid answer.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for closing the question. Anyway, I thank the people who commented, they helped me, and I believe I helped others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why you think, that text rotated for 270 degree is more readable as when is rotated for 90 degree? For example, article are in journals or in proceedings are usual twoside. In such cases your document and table preamble is as follows:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%------ tables
\usepackage[clockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{bgodd}{black!10}
\usepackage{tabularray}
     \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{Papers analyzed in the survey grouped by data sources employed, and techniques used to detect anomalies.}
\renewcommand\cellrotangle{270}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\small Monitoring-Based}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\textheight,  % <--- added
        colspec = {l *{13}{X[c]}},
        vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{dotted},
        vline{2,5} = {1-Z}{solid, \lightrulewidth}, % \lightrulewidth is defined in booktabs
        colsep = 2pt,                               % <--- changed
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
        row{2} = {cmd=\rotcell},
        row{odd [3-Y]} = {bg=bgodd},                % <--- changed
                }
% table body
...
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

which gives (after two compilation) the following result:

[image]

As you can see, now rotated text start on odd pages at top of the second row, and on even pages at the bottom of the second table row. Is this, what you are after?

**Addendum:**
It may be handy the following solution:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
%------ tables
\usepackage[clockwise]{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{xifthen}
%\ifthenelse{\isodd{thepage}}{\renewcommand\cellrotangle{90}}{\renewcommand\cellrotangle{270}} % start at top of row
\ifthenelse{\isodd{thepage}}{\renewcommand\cellrotangle{270}}{\renewcommand\cellrotangle{90}}  % start at bottom of row

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{bgodd}{black!10}
\usepackage{tabularray}
     \UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable*}[ht]
    \centering
\caption{Papers analyzed in the survey grouped by data sources employed, and techniques used to detect anomalies.}
\label{tab:tbl_results}
\settowidth\rotheadsize{\small Monitoring-Based}
\footnotesize
    \begin{tblr}{
        width=\textheight,  % <--- added
        colspec = {l *{13}{X[c]}},
        vline{2-Y} = {2-Z}{dotted},
        vline{2,5} = {1-Z}{solid, \lightrulewidth}, % \lightrulewidth is defined in booktabs
        colsep = 2pt,                               % <--- changed
        row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m},
        row{2} = {cmd=\rotcell},
        row{odd [3-Y]} = {bg=bgodd},                % <--- changed
                }
% table body
        \toprule
...
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{sidewaystable*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the post to make it clearer, @Celdor's solution worked.

Comment: @MS-SPO, thank you very much for edits!

Comment: @Zarko, no problem: you should see my typos from time to time ... Meanwhile I understand corrections in my posts more as a friendly peer-review, which is a good thing.